# Boolean to string wherever present in code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, microsoft-edge

I have an app platform which is developed on "Edge". And my app is built on eclipse. In javascript files of my code many times i have declared my variables with boolean. But to run app on platform i have to convert these boolean values to string like "true". Then only i can set it true. In a big code it is not good to convert boolean to string everywhere. So is it possible that wherever i am having boolean value it can detect and convert to string so that the app platform developed on Edge can understand it ?

Comment: Why would you want a string value of a boolean? That negates the whole purpose of a boolean

Comment: If i set Var value=true; and put alert(value) i am getting it as undefined. But if i am setting it as var value="true"; i am getting expected true answer.

Comment: This is confusing.  When you say "Edge" do you mean the browser for the  client user? And when you say "Eclipse" do you mean the IDE that you used to build your server functionality (perhaps, using JAVA)?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you try to print out `boolean` values in the first place? Check to see if value is `boolean` where you are `alert(value);`

For example,

```js
   var value = true; // Somewhere in code

    if (value == true) { // Just check if value is true/false
        alert("true");
    } else {
        alert("false");
    }
```

Your approach is unnecessary and you are making the problem more complex then needs to be. There is no way to *check* if a value is `boolean` while the code is running, so you are going to have to change it everywhere you want `alert("true");` Sadly, you can't *hack* this with a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But you are not getting my problem. Please understand it. I know it's of no meaning but to run my app on Microsoft Edge platform..i have to convert all the boolean values into string. In the above code i will be getting "false" as output since the value is not set to true (because we have declared it in boolean and not string). I know its complex or unbelievable.but trust me..this is what happening in the code..